# What is the recommended way to configure DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dns-zone, dns-hosting, amazon-lightsail

Not sure if this is the right SE to ask the question, if not please kindly direct me to the right SE.

**Brief background:**
I am learning VPC and started with AWS lightsail(wordpress). I just realised it doesn't come with email service and have to be set up on our own.

**What I want to do:**
I'd prefer to use a non Amazon's email service provider (maybe proton or g-suite) for daily email communications.

I'd prefer to have www.example.com to be redirected to example.com.

**My questions:**

1. What is the recommended way to set up the email MX record?
2. Does it make any difference in configuring DNS with domain registrar or hosting service provider?
3. I remember Google Analytics has the option to direct www.example.com to example.com and vice versa. Is it similar to DNS directing or that is mainly for site traffic direction?
4. Is it more recommended to use Amazon workmail since I am using the lightsail?

**Extra info:**
Currently, the domain is registered with Namecheap and I have the NS pointed to AWS. I'm open to any kind of configuration suggestions because it is mainly for learning purpose and can be changed/deleted anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have web on AWS and email elsewhere, no problem. They are independent services.

1. The MX records for G-Suite are documented here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en, simply create them in AWS Route53.
2. Host your domain where you like. However having it at AWS Route53 enables some neat integrations with other AWS services that you may enjoy later when you get more advanced.
3. Redirection is done on the web server (Apache) or on the Load Balancer if you use one. See [Apache redirect non-www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www) (works the same from www to non-www).
4. Nope, doesn't matter. It may be a little easier to configure since WorkMail can auto-populate the MX records in your Route53 zone but it's just a one-off task anyway.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Nice answer. I would add (re question 3) clarify that there is no such thing as web redirecting in DNS (unless you stretch the definition of an A record to breaking point, and even so the actual redirection happens at the web server)

Comment: thanks MLu and @davidgo. That helps a lot. I've another question if you don't mind. If I use Workmail, in events that an instance is stopped, deleted or screwed up, will that affect the email service too? since they are all handled by AWS..

Comment: @Jalene no Workmail has nothing to do with the EC2 instances. As long as the MX records in DNS are correct it will work.